# How to create GPT partitioned bootable USB for uefi? I am on ubuntu and am trying to get back to windows

Tags: 13.04, windows-8, live-usb, uefi, gpt

Basically I am trying to get back to windows so I can play league of legends on this pc. Any and all help is appreciated. I am not enjoying playing on ubuntu with playonlinux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on) Why do you need to “create GPT partitioned bootable USB for uefi”?

Answer (score 0):

If Windows is still installed on your computer but you're unable to boot it, try using the USB flash drive version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) Note, however, that rEFInd requires extra configuration if Secure Boot is enabled, so if you've not already done so, you'll need to [disable Secure Boot](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) to get this to work. (Depending on what's wrong with your system now, that might get Windows booting without using rEFInd.)